# Where is installation prefix set?

Tags: software-installation, compiling, configure

I see that my programs install to `usr/local/bin` and that I can change that if I do `./configure --prefix=/usr/` at the build.

Where is the default prefix specified? Where can I change the default? Is it possible to change the default installation to `/usr/bin/` for my program only instead of changing the default for the user?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Installing locally built applications with prefix `/usr` is a really bad idea as the files installed may easily overwrite files installed by package managers.  This may later give you issues if the package managers gets confused when file checksums no longer match, or when there are mismatches between executables and libraries.

`/usr/local` is the correct place to install locally compiled software on most systems, although `/opt` may be a safer (most BSD Unices uses `/usr/local` for third party software).

I would definitely not recommend trying to change the default prefix.

Having said that, it is defined in the file `general.m4` in the `autoconf` distribution as the variable `as_default_prefix`. On my OpenBSD system, this file resides in `/usr/local/share/autoconf-2.69/autoconf`. This directory may be located elsewhere if you're on Linux or use another version of `autoconf`.

This variable would have to be changed in the `autoconf` distribution and any `configure` script would have to be re-generated (as this variable is inserted in the `configure` script by `autoconf` when it's created).

An easier way would be to create a `config.site` file as described in [the `autoconf` documentation](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/Site-Defaults.html#Site-Defaults) and set the value of `prefix`.

Again, changing this would most definitely lead to shooting yourself in the foot further down the line.

See also: [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard).

Comment: To expand a bit on the answer, software that doesn't use autotools may define it in a local makefile or equivalent. `/usr/local` is the standard place to install locally compiled software, so it's not necessarily "configurable" system-wide. And as Kusalananda points out, you most likely should not change it to `/usr` anyway.